# VS Code auto wrap Lua code with auro wrap disabled when formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

Im having a strange issue with VSC, since some days ago, a week at most, VSC started to auto wrap large lines, even when auto wrap its disabled and I dont have any plugin installed that wrap stuff.
Checked my configs and all auto wrap and wrap related settings are disabled, any help its really appreciated since I use a lot of auto format and the hard wrapping its killing me.

Here is an example line that gets wrapped:

```
local canPlace = af.chekValidPosition(context.user_id, dbDump[1].value.buildings, json.orientation.x, json.orientation.y, buildInformation.size.x, buildInformation.size.y, layoutToUse)
```

It ends up like this:

```
local canPlace = af.chekValidPosition(context.user_id, dbDump[1].value.buildings, json.orientation.x,
        json.orientation.y, buildInformation.size.x, buildInformation.size.y, layoutToUse)
```

This is the full list of extensions I use, just in case Im missing something.

- C/C++
- C#
- Docker
- Go
- Lua
- Lua Debug
- Peacock
- PowerShell
- Remote - Containers

To add to this, the Lua extension seems to be the one causing this issue.

I get this error checking the configuration for that extension:

```
Lua › Format: Default Config
%config.format.defaultConfig%
Incorrect type. Expected an object.
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this same issue with sumneko's Lua plugin, you need to either add a editorconfig file to your project's root or add the max_line_length parameter and set a new value, default one its 120.